# How to reference a subfolder of a shared mailbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save Outlook attachments to a shared drive.

The below script saves attachments from my own inbox. I want to save attachments from a *subfolder* of a shared mailbox.

```
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Const attPath As String = "T:\London File3 Group\Client Reporting\Test\ABI Daily\"

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application: Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set InboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Msg             As Outlook.MailItem: Set Msg = Item
    Dim olDestFldr      As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments   As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim Filename        As String

    If Not TypeName(Msg) = "MailItem" Then Exit Sub
    If (Msg.Subject Like "*Trade*") Or (Msg.Subject Like "*Trades*") Or _
      (Msg.Subject Like "*Article 59*") Or (Msg.Subject Like "*Val*") Or _
      (Msg.Subject Like "*Valuation*") Or (Msg.Subject Like "*Trading*") Or _
      (Msg.Subject Like "*St James*") Then
    
        Set myAttachments = Item.Attachments
        Filename = myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Filename
        Msg.UnRead = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Work with [GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220116(v=office.11)) which Returns a MAPIFolder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders*

*Example*

```
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Const attPath As String = "T:\London File3 Group\Client Reporting\Test\ABI Daily\"

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application: Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim ShrdRecip As Outlook.Recipient: Set ShrdRecip = objectNS.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com")

    Set InboxItems = GetSharedDefaultFolder(ShrdRecip, olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
```

***Edit***

*Example for subfolder*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim ShrdRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ShrdRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(ShrdRecip, olFolderInbox) _
                                                .Folders("FolderName")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject ' print on Immediate window
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I reference a subfolder of the shared recipient? Also I'm guessing you meant objectNS instead of olNs in line 6? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, yes this is what im looking for but are you able to edit it including the all of the code? i.e the If statements in my first post.  I'm struggling to see what you've omitted.