# Outlook Shared Contacts copied to MyContacts

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to copy Outlook Shared Contacts into a folder under MyContacts. I am looking for an easy solution for my team outside of using an Import Wizard or physically copy/paste due to the computer challenged. I have been successful in doing this from MyContacts/Contacts to MyContacts/Another_Folder but can't seem to copy from a Shared Contact folder.

I am running a macro from Excel so that all users can just run the Excel macro and it will modify their Outlook instead of having everyone Allow macros in Outlook.

Current running code is here:

```
Sub CopyContacts()

Dim ContactItem As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim Name As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Dim Item As Object

Set Name = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set Folder = Name.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)

    For Each Item In Folder.Items

        If Item.Class = olContact Then

        Set ContactItem = Item.Copy
        ContactItem.Move Folder.Folders("Another_Folder")

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I would like to run an Excel Macro to copy all the contents from Shared Contacts John Doe's folder to Another_Folder.

[image: Outlook Contact Folder Structure]

I would be great if the Macro deleted all the contents from Another_Folder before the copy function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference a subfolder of a shared mailbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045295/how-to-reference-a-subfolder-of-a-shared-mailbox)

Comment: Where is the folder located? Switch to the Folder View to see the treeview filled with folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("John Doe") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  Call ShowContacts(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowContacts(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim ContactsFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set ContactsFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderContacts) 
 
 ContactsFolder.Display 
 
End Sub
```